# Последняя вкладка tab-а меняется только при выборе одного из пунктов в выпадающем списке

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $('ul.tabs li').click(function(){
  var tab_id = $(this).attr('data-tab');
  $('ul.tabs li').removeClass('current');
  $('.tab-content').removeClass('current');
  $(this).addClass('current');
  $("#"+tab_id).addClass('current');
 })
})
```

```css
.tab-link span{font-size: 16px; padding: 8px 0; color: #ABABAB; line-height: 1.5;}
.tab-link div{width: 180px;
    height: 110px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;cursor: pointer;}
 ul.tabs{
   margin: 0px;
   padding: 0px;
   list-style: none;
   display: flex;
      justify-content: space-between;
  }
}
}
ul.tabs li{
   background: none;
   color: #222;
   display: inline-block;
   padding: 10px 15px;
   cursor: pointer;
  }
ul.tabs li.current{
   background: #3A71FF;
   border-radius: 5px;
   
  }
li.current span{color: #fff;}
.tab-content{
   display: none;
   margin-top: 37px;
  }
.tab-content.current{
   display: inherit;
  }
.tab_txt_tit{font-size: 22px;font-family: 'ProximaNova-Bold';}
.tab_txt{font-size: 16px;}
.hov_img path{fill:red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="our_services">
 <ul class="tabs">
  <li class="tab-link current" data-tab="tab-1"><div class="d_flex d_column"><img src="img/tab_1.svg" class="hov_img"><span>Грузоперевозки</span></div></li>
  <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-2"><div class="d_flex d_column"><img src="img/tab_2.svg"><span>Сварочные работы</span></div></li>
  <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-3"><div class="d_flex d_column"><img src="img/tab_3.svg"><span>Металлоконструкции</span></div></li>
  <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-4"><div class="d_flex d_column"><img src="img/tab_4.svg"><span>Резка металла</span></div></li>
  <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-5"><div class="d_flex d_column"><img src="img/tab_5.svg"><span>Размотка металла</span></div></li>
  <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-6"><div class="d_flex d_column"><img src="img/tab_dots.svg"><span>Остальные услуги</span></div></li>
  <!--<li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-7"><div class="d_flex d_column"><img src="img/tab_6.svg"><span>Услуги манипулятора</span></div></li>
  <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-8"><div class="d_flex d_column"><img src="img/tab_7.svg"><span>Услуги эксковатора</span></div></li>-->
 </ul>

 <div id="tab-1" class="tab-content current">
  <div class="d_flex">
   <div class="tab_img"><img src="img/tab_img.jpg"></div>
   <div class="tab_txt">
    <span class="tab_txt_tit">Грузоперевозки</span>
    <p>Благодаря современным технологиям и невероятно «умному» оборудованию обычная и традиционная резка металла превратилась в искусство. Сложность линии реза, высочайшая точность, резка по металлу различного качества, возможность обработки сложных заготовок — далеко не полный перечень работ, входящих в услуги по резке металла.</p>
    <p>Мы готовы предоставить услуги порезки металлопроката любых объемов и сложностей</p>
    <div class="d_flex"><a href=""><div><span>Заказать услугу</span><img src=""></div></a><a href=""><div><span>Все услуги</span><img src=""></div></a></div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div id="tab-2" class="tab-content">
   <div class="d_flex">
   <div class="tab_img"><img src="img/tab_img.jpg"></div>
   <div class="tab_txt">
    <span class="tab_txt_tit">Сварочные работы</span>
    <p>Благодаря современным технологиям и невероятно «умному» оборудованию обычная и традиционная резка металла превратилась в искусство. Сложность линии реза, высочайшая точность, резка по металлу различного качества, возможность обработки сложных заготовок — далеко не полный перечень работ, входящих в услуги по резке металла.</p>
    <p>Мы готовы предоставить услуги порезки металлопроката любых объемов и сложностей</p>
    <div class="d_flex"><a href=""><div><span>Заказать услугу</span><img src=""></div></a><a href=""><div><span>Все услуги</span><img src=""></div></a></div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div id="tab-3" class="tab-content">
  <div class="d_flex">
   <div class="tab_img"><img src="img/tab_img.jpg"></div>
   <div class="tab_txt">
    <span class="tab_txt_tit">Металлоконструкции</span>
    <p>Благодаря современным технологиям и невероятно «умному» оборудованию обычная и традиционная резка металла превратилась в искусство. Сложность линии реза, высочайшая точность, резка по металлу различного качества, возможность обработки сложных заготовок — далеко не полный перечень работ, входящих в услуги по резке металла.</p>
    <p>Мы готовы предоставить услуги порезки металлопроката любых объемов и сложностей</p>
    <div class="d_flex"><a href=""><div><span>Заказать услугу</span><img src=""></div></a><a href=""><div><span>Все услуги</span><img src=""></div></a></div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div id="tab-4" class="tab-content">
  <div class="d_flex">
   <div class="tab_img"><img src="img/tab_img.jpg"></div>
   <div class="tab_txt">
    <span class="tab_txt_tit">Резка металла</span>
    <p>Благодаря современным технологиям и невероятно «умному» оборудованию обычная и традиционная резка металла превратилась в искусство. Сложность линии реза, высочайшая точность, резка по металлу различного качества, возможность обработки сложных заготовок — далеко не полный перечень работ, входящих в услуги по резке металла.</p>
    <p>Мы готовы предоставить услуги порезки металлопроката любых объемов и сложностей</p>
    <div class="d_flex"><a href=""><div><span>Заказать услугу</span><img src=""></div></a><a href=""><div><span>Все услуги</span><img src=""></div></a></div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div id="tab-5" class="tab-content">
  <div class="d_flex">
   <div class="tab_img"><img src="img/tab_img.jpg"></div>
   <div class="tab_txt">
    <span class="tab_txt_tit">Размотка металла</span>
    <p>Благодаря современным технологиям и невероятно «умному» оборудованию обычная и традиционная резка металла превратилась в искусство. Сложность линии реза, высочайшая точность, резка по металлу различного качества, возможность обработки сложных заготовок — далеко не полный перечень работ, входящих в услуги по резке металла.</p>
    <p>Мы готовы предоставить услуги порезки металлопроката любых объемов и сложностей</p>
    <div class="d_flex"><a href=""><div><span>Заказать услугу</span><img src=""></div></a><a href=""><div><span>Все услуги</span><img src=""></div></a></div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div id="tab-6" class="tab-content">
  <div class="d_flex">
   <div class="tab_img"><img src="img/tab_img.jpg"></div>
   <div class="tab_txt">
    <span class="tab_txt_tit">Остальные услуги</span>
    <p>Благодаря современным технологиям и невероятно «умному» оборудованию обычная и традиционная резка металла превратилась в искусство. Сложность линии реза, высочайшая точность, резка по металлу различного качества, возможность обработки сложных заготовок — далеко не полный перечень работ, входящих в услуги по резке металла.</p>
    <p>Мы готовы предоставить услуги порезки металлопроката любых объемов и сложностей</p>
    <div class="d_flex"><a href=""><div><span>Заказать услугу</span><img src=""></div></a><a href=""><div><span>Все услуги</span><img src=""></div></a></div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <!--<div id="tab-7" class="tab-content">
  <div class="d_flex">
   <div class="tab_img"><img src="img/tab_img.jpg"></div>
   <div class="tab_txt">
    <span class="tab_txt_tit">Услуги манипулятора</span>
    <p>Благодаря современным технологиям и невероятно «умному» оборудованию обычная и традиционная резка металла превратилась в искусство. Сложность линии реза, высочайшая точность, резка по металлу различного качества, возможность обработки сложных заготовок — далеко не полный перечень работ, входящих в услуги по резке металла.</p>
    <p>Мы готовы предоставить услуги порезки металлопроката любых объемов и сложностей</p>
    <div class="d_flex"><a href=""><div><span>Заказать услугу</span><img src=""></div></a><a href=""><div><span>Все услуги</span><img src=""></div></a></div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div id="tab-8" class="tab-content">
  <div class="d_flex">
   <div class="tab_img"><img src="img/tab_img.jpg"></div>
   <div class="tab_txt">
    <span class="tab_txt_tit">Услуги эксковатора</span>
    <p>Благодаря современным технологиям и невероятно «умному» оборудованию обычная и традиционная резка металла превратилась в искусство. Сложность линии реза, высочайшая точность, резка по металлу различного качества, возможность обработки сложных заготовок — далеко не полный перечень работ, входящих в услуги по резке металла.</p>
    <p>Мы готовы предоставить услуги порезки металлопроката любых объемов и сложностей</p>
    <div class="d_flex"><a href=""><div><span>Заказать услугу</span><img src=""></div></a><a href=""><div><span>Все услуги</span><img src=""></div></a></div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>-->
    </div>
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно сделать так, чтобы при наведении на последнюю вкладку tab-а, открывался соответствующий выбранный таб? Или есть ли ссылки на примеры? Я видимо не так ищу.
[image: Скрин]

Comment: А вкладки, которые расположены горизонтально нормально отрабатывают при наведении?

Comment: @РустамГимранов все вкладки горизонтальные они нормально работают то есть открывается соответствующая вкладка, а наведение должно быть именно на последней вкладке, проблема именно в этом, при выборе из выпадающего меню открывалась вкладка соответствующей услуги, в данном случае "услуги манипулятора" и "услуги экскаватора"

Comment: Не думаю, что ваша проблема не решаема, но изложена не понятно. На изображении акцент сделан на вкладках из выпадающего списка, но в коде они закомментированы. Отсюда неясность, что в итоге быть должно?